# How can I generically call super().method(), without explicitly passing in the current class?

Tags: python

I know I can do:

```
class Foo(Object):
   @classmethod
   def run(cls):
      // do stuff

class Bar(Foo):      
   @classmethod:
   def run(cls):
      super(Bar, cls).run()
      // do more stuff
```

However, what I want to do is more along the lines of `super(cls.__name__, cls).run()`. This unfortunately doesn't work, with the error:

```
super(cls.__name__, cls).run(cls)
TypeError: must be type, not str
```

Comment: You cannot in Python 2. Upgrade to Python 3. And do *not* use `self.__class__`.

Comment: Upgrading to Python 3 isn't an option. Thanks though

Comment: I've duped you to an answer of mine that explains why you *have* to pass in the class object explicitly. There is no short-cut here.